# Angular ng-repeat without html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm in trouble with a foreach that I need to do with Angular.

Thats's what I want to do :

```
<ul>
    <div ng-repeat="g in groups">
        <li ng-repeat="c in g.commands">{{c.text}}</li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

How can I do something like that, but in valid HTML structure ? (without a `<div>` between `<ul>` and `<li>`)

I see only one solution :

- Replace the `<div>` with a `<ul>` and make a lot of css rules to make it like it doesn't exists

In addition, I use Angular 1.4.8.

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you use a `div`?

Comment: @AntiHeadshot The structure `<ul>` > `<div>` > `<li>` is not a valid HTML. If it was a valid structure, I would certainly have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to alter your data structure at all.  Instead just utilize the `ng-repeat-start` & `ng-repeat-end` directive.  You'll have separate `<ul>`s but in terms of rendering, you can easily modify the CSS to make it appear to be a seamless list.

```
<ul ng-repeat-start="g in groups">
    <li ng-repeat="c in g.commands">{{c.text}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat-end class="divider"></li>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/KVZBLv

Comment: Yes that's the solution I've choosen. But I was hoping that I can have that render without multiples `<ul>`.

Comment: Unfortunately you will not be able to do that unless you create a directive or change the data structure as @Sebastian has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to use a custom collection `groupedCommands` that is bound to the angular scope in code and contains the items in the correct order.

Then use [ng-repeat-start](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for the enhanced repeat directive. There is a special `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` attribute combination that you can use for this case:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat-start="c in groupedCommands">{{c.text}}</li>
   <li class="divider" ng-repeat-end></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know that but this doesn't solve my problem. I have two lists to repeat.

Comment: Thank you but I prefer jusopi's answer.

Answer (score -3):

Try This one,

```
<ul>
    <!-- ng-repeat: g in groups -->
    <span ng-repeat="g in groups">
        <li ng-repeat="c in g.commands">{{c.text}}</li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
    </span>
</ul>
```

This may solve your problem.

**Caution :** It is not a good way to use `<span>` between `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Comment: Yes it will solve my problem but that's not the good way. I can't use a `<span>` between `<ul>` and `<li>`.